# Why is an empty list returned when solving for this linear system in Maxima?

Tags: solver, maxima, equation-solving, linear-equation

I'm trying to solve a simple linear system in Maxima using [`solve`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_20.html#solve) like so:

```
/*Standard form*/
eq1 : x1 + 3*x2  + s1 = 6;
eq2 : 3*x1 + 2*x2 + s2 = 6;

base1 : solve([eq1,eq2],[s1,s2]);
```

This however returns an empty list and I don't know why. Any ideas? I'm pretty sure the system has a solution, so that shouldn't be the issue.

### EDIT:

I attempted to insert the equations explicitly into `solve` in place of `eq1` and `eq2`, and now it works. Now the question is, why do I need to explicitly insert the equations to be solved for into the first argument of `solve`. An in-depth answer about how Maxima works in this case would be welcome.

Comment: I don't get an empty list from `solve`, instead I get: `[[s1 = (-3*x2)-x1+6,s2 = (-2*x2)-3*x1+6]]`. I am working with Maxima 5.41.0 + SBCL 1.3.14 on Linux (Debian). What does `build_info` report on your system? Are you working with command line Maxima or wxMaxima or another user interface?

Comment: I&#39;m (once again) building a homework problem on Moodle STACK. Our Moodle was recently updated with the latest version of STACK, so something might have changed. In any case, it was annoying to have to copy the entire equations into `solve` multiple times. It also made the implementation unnecessarily messy.

Comment: OK, I'm still kind of wondering about the Maxima, Lisp, and operating system version. Is there any way to find out? On a separate note, is it possible that Moodle and/or STACK has done something unexpected like disabling evaluation and/or simplification?

Comment: I sit next to our "Moodle person" at work, so I could ask him tomorrow.

Comment: OK. It occurs to me maybe one or more of the names eq1, eq2, s1, or s2 are special to STACK and/or Moodle somehow. Just a random speculation.

Comment: I've used `eq1` and `eq2` before and those weren't a problem. In any case Maxima version 5.41.0, REHL 7.5 and Lisp SBCL 1.4.0-1.el7 are the ones used here.

Comment: OK. Can you run whatever Maxima is executed by STACK at the command line and try the same inputs?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when one of the variables in the equation was previously defined.

E.g., if `z` was previously defined:

[image]

Then simply changing `z` to, e.g., `p` returns the solutions:

[image]