# Subsitute a solution of a matrix equation into a matrix product in maxima

Tags: moodle, symbolic-math, maxima

I'm trying to do the following in Maxima (within Moodle STACK):

```
c : matrix([5],[3],[1],[0],[0])
x : matrix([x1],[x2],[x3],[s1],[s2]);
base0 : matrix([0],[0],[5],[0],[1]);

z : transpose(c).x;
zval : subst(base0,x,z);
```

but all I get as output is `x3+3⋅x2+5⋅x1`, which is supposed to be the numerical value of the function `z` at the point `base0`. I had [**a similar problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51301955/why-is-an-empty-list-returned-when-solving-for-this-linear-system-in-maxima) with the `solve`-function a little while back, but this time not even the explicit insertion of the components into the expression like so

```
zval : subst(matrix([0],[0],[5],[0],[1]),matrix([x1],[x2],[x3],[s1],[s2]),matrix([5],[3],[1],[0],[0]).matrix([x1],[x2],[x3],[s1],[s2]));
```

works. The problem with `solve` was never fixed, so I'm wondering if I'm just going to have to calculate things by hand from now on.

Comment: I'm still curious about the `solve` problem. I was asking about some additional info, if you have anything you could mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subst` is solely a syntactic substitution -- it is looking for an explicit occurrence of the value `x` in `z`, and it doesn't guess that you mean to equate the i'th elements of `base0` and `x`.

I get what I think is the intended result by constructing a list of equations to represent the intended substitutions.

```
(%i6) eqs:makelist(x[i,1] = base0[i,1],i,1,5)
(%o6)              [x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 5, s1 = 0, s2 = 1]
(%i7) zval:subst(eqs,z)
(%o7)                                  5
```